# Simplificar operacion matricial y vectorizada en una sola funcion con numpy

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, python-3.7

Me encuentro evaluando una matriz en una operacion matematica con numpy de la siguiente manera:

```
def funcion(self,matriz):
    x = matriz[:,0]
    y = matriz[:,1]
    fx = np.power((x-100),2) + np.power((y-90),3)
```

como podemos notar la matriz que recibe el metodo es de 2xN la primea columna representa las ***x*** y la segunda columna el valor de las ***y***, haciendo los calculos de manera vectorizada.¡Hasta allì no hay problema! el problema viene cuando en vez de una matriz  quiero evaluar un vector o mas bien una matriz 2x1, en dicho caso no sirve mi codigo anterior por lo que me toca crear un metodo asi:

```
def funcion(self,matriz):
    x = matriz[0]
    y = matriz[1]
    fx = np.power((x-100),2) + np.power((y-90),3)
```

mi pregunta es: ¿Como puedo diseñar una funcion tal que sin importar si es una matriz o un vector esta me haga la operacion indicada?

Comment: Comprueba `matriz.ndim` dentro de la función y asigna x,y en consecuencia

Comment: Despues de comprobar el tamaño de la matriz, como hago para evitar el condicional if matriz.ndim == 1 .... haga esto
else: ..... haga lo otro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A través de `matriz.ndim` puedes ver cuántas dimensiones tiene la matriz. Para que el código de tu primera función no dé errores, la matriz ha de ser de dimensión 2. Si es de dimensión 1 se producirá un error debido a la sintaxis `[:, ...]`, pues estás usando un slice de dos dimensiones.

Asi que se me ocurren tres formas de abordar tu problema:

1. Asignar `x` e `y` de forma diferente según el número de dimensiones
2. Forzar a que `matriz` tenga dos dimensiones cuando tiene una
3. ¡Truco! Usar desempaquetado de tuplas. Creo que este te interesará

Veámoslos

### Asignación condicional

No tiene misterio, según la dimensión `x` e `y` se asignan de forma diferente mediante un condicional. La fórmula que hace el cómputo queda como estaba.

```py
def funcion(matriz):
    if matriz.ndim == 1:
        x = matriz[0]
        y = matriz[1]
    else:
        x = matriz[:, 0]
        y = matriz[:, 1]
    fx = np.power((x-100),2) + np.power((y-90),3) 
    return fx
```

Demo:

```
a = np.array([[101,91], [102,92]])
print(funcion(a))  # ----------------> [2 12]

a = np.array([101,91])
print(funcion(a))  # ----------------> 2
```

Observa que si `a` es un vector el resultado es un escalar (2) y no un vector. Pero esto ya estaba así en tu código original.

### Forzar a dos dimensiones

En este caso modificamos `matriz` si su `ndim` es 1, en la forma siguiente:

```
def funcion(matriz):
    if matriz.ndim == 1:
        matriz = np.array([matriz])
    x = matriz[:,0]
    y = matriz[:,1]
    fx = np.power((x-100),2) + np.power((y-90),3) 
    return fx
```

Como ves, anidamos `[matriz]` un nivel más. Gracias a eso el slice `[:, ...]` ya funcionará sin errores. Observa que ahora el resultado devuelto por la función será siempre un vector, tanto si la entrada es una matriz como si es un vector.

Demo:

```
a = np.array([[101,91], [102,92]])
print(funcion(a))         # -----------> [2 12] igual que antes

a = np.array([101,91])
print(funcion(a))         # -----------> [2]  un vector de un solo elemento
```

### Truco. Desempaquetado de tuplas

Me he fijado que, en la primera solución, las asignaciones `x = matriz[0]` e `y = matriz[1]` pueden escribirse en una sola línea así:

```
x, y = matriz
```

gracias al desempaquetado automático de tuplas que python puede hacer en asignaciones como esta (con tal de que a la derecha del `=` haya un iterable con tantos elementos como la tupla de la izquierda). El primer elemento de `matriz` será asignado a `x` y el segundo a `y`.

Pero ¡un momento! la misma sintaxis sirve si `matriz` es bidimensional. En este caso el primer elemento de `matriz` es la primera fila, que sería asignada a `x` y el segundo elemento es la segunda fila, que sería asignado a `y`. Casi lo tenemos, sólo que queremos que sean columnas. Basta por tanto transponer la matriz antes de hacer esa asignación. Es decir:

```
x, y = matriz.T
```

Pero ¡un momento! (otra vez) Esta asignación que usa la transpuesta servirá también para el caso en que `matriz` tenga una sola dimensión, pues en este caso transponer el vector no lo modifica (por ser unidimensional).

Eso nos permite escribir la siguiente función, válida tanto si `matriz` tiene una dimensión como si tiene dos:

```
def funcion(matriz):
    x, y = matriz.T
    fx = np.power((x-100),2) + np.power((y-90),3) 
    return fx
```

Demo:

```
a = np.array([[101,91], [102,92]])
print(funcion(a))      # --------------> [2 12] Sale correctamente lo de antes

a = np.array([101,91])
print(funcion(a))      # --------------> 2 Y aqui también
```

Observa que, al igual que en la primera solución, el resultado será un vector o un escalar según el número de dimensiones de la matriz, por lo que debido a este detalle quizás prefieras usar la solución 2.